# OpenLiteSpeed and cache

Tags: caching, prestashop, openlitespeed

I am testing a Cyberpanel + Openlitespeed webserver with a Prestashop site.

Default config for the Litespeed module is:
checkPrivateCache   1
checkPublicCache    1
maxCacheObjSize     10000000
maxStaleAge         200
qsCache             1
reqCookieCache      1
respCookieCache     1
ignoreReqCacheCtrl  1
ignoreRespCacheCtrl 0

enableCache         0
expireInSeconds     3600
enablePrivateCache  0
privateExpireInSeconds 3600

I've seen that if I change enableCache to 1, the web loads faster, but the backend donest work and don't save changes.
The only way to to work with Prestashop and OLScache is with the Enterprise and the Prestashop module?
Thanks

Comment: what you did is like unconditionally cache all pages, including admin ,  you need to work out some basic rewrite rule to control the cache , or use the enterprise with module.